# Subfloat caption in wrong position

Tags: positioning, captions, subfloats

My subfloat command is standard and simple:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig,caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \subfloat[illegitimate]{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{QR.eps}}
  \qquad
  \subfloat[legitimate]{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{anti02.eps}}
  \caption{QR code}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And I end up getting something like this, with the captions shifted away to the right:

```
p i c t u r e 1     p i c t u r e 2     

                   (a) illegitimate     (b) legitimate
```

Why are the captions shifted so far away instead of staying under the pictures? The pictures are of equal and appropriate sizes and there're plenty of space to move around!

**Edit:**  I checked out the log file, which seems to say something's wrong with the picture anti02. What could be wrong, please?

```
LaTeX Warning: Label `' multiply defined.

) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(E:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd)
(E:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd) [1] [2]
(E:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\omscmr.fd) [3] [4] [5] [6] <QR.eps>
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 291--291
[]

Overfull \hbox (233.31259pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 291--291
[] 
<anti02.eps>
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 293--293
[][]

Overfull \hbox (233.31259pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 293--293
[] 
[7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] ("C:\Users\eric\Desktop\number guessing——test.aux"
)
```

---

**2nd Edit:** I removed this command:

```
\setcaptionwidth{5in}
```

in preamble and it worked right. But why?

Comment: It works fine for me. What versions of `subfig` and `caption` are you using?

Comment: @Jake: I don't know. I downloaded the whole thing as a package. How could this matter?

Comment: Maybe you're using an old version of one of the packages that had a bug in it. If you add `\listfiles` to your preamble, the versions of the packages will be printed near the end of the `.log` file. I have `subfig.sty 2005/06/28 ver: 1.3` and `caption.sty 2011/11/10 v3.2e`. Can you also try using `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` to load the `graphicx` package and see whether you still get the incorrect results?

Comment: Does the problem occur with the exact code you just posted?

Comment: @Jake: Yes they are exactly the same versions as yours. \usepackage[demo]{graphicx} still gets to same the wrong positions.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Yes, I copy+pasted the code.

Comment: Add `\listfiles` before the `\documentclass` line in the example code, process it and upload the obtained `.log` file. Also, can you please upload somewhere the .eps files that you are using and give us the links?

Comment: But the snippet from the .log file you just added to your question is from a different document! You said the problem was present with the little example code that appears in your question. Please make sure that the code you posted produces the problem.

Comment: @Eric: You can't use the same example because you didn't define any label.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: O, yes! Sorry I misunderstood you. The same problem doesn't occur with just those code alone. It occurs in the the larger context though! Can you see what's wrong from the log?

Comment: No, that snippet doesn't give enough information on the cause of the problem. Reduce your code to a minimal version allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If I modify your MWE so it starts with

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{article}
```

as I don't have your eps files I get the following

[image]

which shows that it works. If you get the same, then remove the `draft` again and try outside of the figure, just in normal text

```
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{QR.eps}}
```

If the box does not surround the figure, it means that the bounding box in the file is incorrect and so the dimensions of the image are not as they appear. if that is the case you can fix the eps file or supply a corrected bounding box using the `bb= 1 2 3 4` key in the optional argument to `\includegraphics` using the correct values not 1 2 3 4!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was being unclear because that code is just part of a larger article. The real problem is this command  \setcaptionwidth{5in} in the preamble. Please see the second edit.

Comment: Ah well what do you expect to happen? you have requested two captions each 5in wide, but the page is not that wide so they can't fit.